# Как получить доступ к кэшу процессора пользователя на JS (Meltdown, Spectre)?

Tags: javascript, безопасность

Нашёл такой пример, но он по-моему не работает.

```js
var TABLE1_STRIDE = 1;
var TABLE1_BYTES = 3;
var probeTable = ['alpha', 'beta', 'corky'];
var simpleByteArray = [0x00, 0x01, 0x02];
var localJunk;
var index = 0;
if (index < simpleByteArray.length) {
    index = simpleByteArray[index | 0];
    index = (((index * TABLE1_STRIDE) | 0) & (TABLE1_BYTES - 1)) | 0;
    localJunk &= probeTable[index | 0] | 0;
}
console.log(localJunk);
```

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Я в мирных целях изучаю.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan не первые)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУкрываться Интересно увидеть пример который хоть что то вытягивает из кэша процессора.

Comment: А с чего бы он должен был откуда то чего то вытягивать ? meltdown работает как минимум за счет измерения скорости доступа к данным. Я не вижу в этом примере какого либо измерения скорости. И лично я вообще не понимаю как это касается JS, который не имеет прямого доступа к процессору и любая самая элементарная строка может раскладываться в вызовы десятков процедур и выполнение десятков ветвлений по каждому из которых механизм предсказания переходов должен делать выводы

Comment: И мне интересно, что за шум подняли вокруг этих уязвимостей, вытащить дествительно интересные данные это надо еще постараться. А вот год назад, когда была обнаружена ошибка в Intel AMT, позволяющая получить удаленно полный контроль над целой массой систем, причем на уровне bios, до любых ограничений ОС, никто не нее не обратил никакого внимания.

Comment: @Mike Т.е. на JS невозможно получить доступ к кэшу процессора?

Comment: @Hipster напрямую явно нет. но ведь разработчики firefox зачем то что то делали, значит что то нашли из того же рода уязвимостей. хотя может они и перестраховались. И интересно google что нибудь для хрома делать будет, в конце концов их группа исследователей одной из первых нашла эту уязвимость в процессорах

Comment: @Mike `но ведь разработчики firefox зачем то что то делали` / `лично я вообще не понимаю как это касается JS` - так meltdown и не причем. вот Spectre да. Только ТС видимо не понял о чем пишет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Подтверждаю, для ТС это тёмный лес.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Почитал я общее описание spectre. По моему раздули из мухи слона. Слишком много специальных условий. Во первых в JS понадобится обратится за пределы массива, причем так, что бы это обращение привело к обращению к некоей переменной в памяти другой вкладки или чего то подобного. Как рассчитать нужное смещение. после того как не будет выполнен if надо померять скорость доступа к нескольким десяткам ячеек массива и при этом не переполнить кеш, что бы искомое не было вытеснено. И надо что бы в это время на этом ядре процессора не обработалось какое нибудь прерывание и т.п.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я понял почему FF забеспокоился. Сначала сделали функцию, которая позволяет обращаться к сырому куску памяти (кроме них только safari ее то же сделал), а теперь в патче ее выключили обратно :) Вот и вся проблема. Еще бы ассемблерный код "для быстроты работы" разрешили бы напрямую из JS выполнять ...

Comment: @Hipster Забейте. Когда выложат готовый эксплоит он будет раз в 100 сложнее приведенного вами куска кода и разобраться в нем будет довольно сложно. Потому что в нем должны быть учтены все тонкости внутреннего построения движка JS в конкретном браузере (FF) ну и с большой вероятностью должен быть использован объект SharedArrayBuffer, а не обычный массив. А приведенный вами кусок кода видимо создан для объяснения "на пальцах" как оно делается (в википедии и то лучше расписано). И да, рабочих эксплоитов никто не выкладывал

Comment: @Hipster не надо создавать бесполезные одноразовые метки